# Redirect to a html page after a successful or failed login using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, authentication, location

Is there a client side solution using only **Javascript** to redirect users to either a **success-login.html** page or a **try-again.html** page?

There is a similar question I found using javascript to control the user login, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333043/redirect-html-page-if-not-login
```

So if anyone out there is a javascript expert that can show me a working script of a basic login form: `username or email` and `password` I will greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I probably know this answer. You want an Script that redirects to a new page after some sort of simple validation with JavaScript.

I've tried it before. Firstly select the form input elements with JavaScript

```
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
```

Write a Relational Statement

```
if(email == "abc@somename.com"){
   //Email will be parsed as String.
   //Redirect to the next page.



return window.location.href='new page.html';
}
else{
   alert('Wrong Email!');
}
```

Try this code, it works fine for me. As I have tested on all major browsers including IE.

You could also validate as many statements using the '&' operator in the 'if' statement.